# Apache Rewrite -> I am not sure why these rules dont work

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am running Apache, CentOS 6.

I have a set of URL's that if they are hit, I want the user directed to the index.php

I cannot figure out why these rules dont work. Can anyone explain?

UPDATE: New Rule Set

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/faculty/gray(/)?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/includes(/)?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images(/)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

None of those conditions will ever match; `%{REQUEST_URI}` always has a leading slash.

Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish, and what other configuration you have in place?  Why's there an `[F]` flag in place, and why are you using a set of conditions that will always evaluate to true regardless of what request is made (since all of your patterns are negative and using the `[OR]` flag)?

Comment: I was trying a different approach and pasted the wrong version of my Include file. I just edited and Updated the correct rule set.

Comment: Ok, so you've gone from some of them working to none of the ones now in the question working - is that correct?  Set a `RewriteLog` location and turn up `RewriteLogLevel 9`.

Comment: If these rules are not in a `<Directory >` context or a .htaccess file, the final rewrite should have a leading slash: `/index.php`.